# How to convert a Jupyter notebook latex markdown file to word?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ms-word, latex, markdown

I've spent a long time making my first Latex type-setted document in jupyter notebooks, but just now I've realised that I want to get it into a word file so that I can send it to my professor to mark. However I can't find a way to get it into word without ruining all my latex (or forcing me to go through and click 'insert equation' in word for every single symbol.) Could someone help?!

Comment: if you want, you can check this page
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53207734/convert-jupyter-notebook-into-ms-word-document-doc

Comment: I am able to convert it to word, but not without destroying my latex

Answer (score 0):

A little convoluted, but you could first convert your jupyter notebook to a latex .tex file (see e.g. https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#convert-latex) and then convert that to Word using some other software (a quick google search shows e.g. https://products.aspose.app/pdf/conversion/tex-to-docx).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can save your file as .tex format, then use pandoc to convert latex to docx, it works for me.

```
pandoc -s document.tex -o document.docx
```