# Export .ipynb file to .docx format in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, docx

I have written a Python notebook `.ipynb` in Visual Studio Code which includes code chunks and markdown chunks. I want to export this file into Microsoft Word `.docx` format. It is easy to export it as `.pdf` but how can I export it into `.docx`?

Any brief solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Jupyter notebook into MS word document .doc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53207734/convert-jupyter-notebook-into-ms-word-document-doc)

Answer (score 1):

convert .ipynb to .md (markdown) and using [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/installing.htmlhttps://) your_input.md -o your_output.docx

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to download the file as a pdf, then open the pdf with Word and 'Save As' docx.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to use [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org). Simply type following command to your Command Prompt:

```bash
pandoc super-secret-notebook.ipynb -s -o export.docx
```

[image]

---

As @I_K suggested, you can export it to a PDF file and then save it as a Word document. Since you have the tag *python* in your question, I assume that you are looking for a Python solution.

Here is an example Python script doing this (requires [`nbconvert`](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io), [`pywin32`](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32), [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/installing.html) and Microsoft Word installed):

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

import subprocess
import win32com.client


PATH_TO_NBCONVERT_EXE = r"C:\apps\python-3.11.1\Scripts\jupyter-nbconvert.exe"

cwd = Path(__file__).parent.resolve()

SCRIPT_PATH = os.path.join(cwd, "super-secret-notebook.ipynb")
FILE_PATH = os.path.join(cwd, "export.docx")

def main():

    subprocess.run(
        ["jupyter-nbconvert", "--execute", "--to", "pdf", SCRIPT_PATH], 
        cwd=cwd, 
        shell=True
    )

    word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")

    doc = word.Documents.Add(SCRIPT_PATH.replace(".ipynb", ".pdf"))
    doc.SaveAs(FILE_PATH, FileFormat=12)
    doc.Close()

    word.Quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output looks a bit different than simply using Pandoc:

[image]

Please note that the script above (and below) is executing `nbconvert` in the command prompt. You could also use the package `nbconvert` in Python itself.

---

Why do you want a Word document? PDF files are easier to distribute. Anyways, if you just need a PDF file, you can generate the file in your Command Prompt as well (without a script):

```bash
jupyter-nbconvert --execute --to pdf super-secret-notebook.ipynb
```

It still requires [`nbconvert`](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io) and [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/installing.html) installed.

---

You can also export to an HTML file and then save it as a Word document. (not requiring Pandoc)

Following Python script executes and exports a Notebook file to HTML and then saves it as a Word document. Formatting is not very useful though.

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

import subprocess
import win32com.client


PATH_TO_NBCONVERT_EXE = r"C:\apps\python-3.11.1\Scripts\jupyter-nbconvert.exe"

cwd = Path(__file__).parent.resolve()

SCRIPT_PATH = os.path.join(cwd, "super-secret-notebook.ipynb")
FILE_PATH = os.path.join(cwd, "export.docx")

def main():

    subprocess.run(
        ["jupyter-nbconvert", "--execute", "--to", "html", SCRIPT_PATH], 
        cwd=cwd, 
        shell=True
    )

    word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")

    doc = word.Documents.Add(SCRIPT_PATH.replace(".ipynb", ".html"))
    doc.SaveAs(FILE_PATH, FileFormat=12)
    doc.Close()

    word.Quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

---

Off-topic: Just some note if anyone comes across this answer and is wondering where to find the constants for the `FileFormat` parameter:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdsaveformat